# how to delete iTune SDK c# in dynamic Playlist?

Tags: c#, itunes, itunes-sdk

I want to erase a iTunes Playlist entry from a dynamic playlist in c#.
With normal playlists i don't have any problem, but iTunes don't want to touch dynamic playlists.

can u give me an advice ?
Ta

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic playlist"? and what do you mean by "erase"? do you want to delete songs from a playlist, or delete a playlist?

Comment: I want to delete a song from a smart playlist (i' am new to itunes).

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to delete songs from a smart playlist. These lists are created based on conditions. If a song satisfies the conditions, it is part of the smart playlist. Deleting individual songs does not make sense then.